# Implement scrolling in custom view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, horizontal-scrolling

I need to create a custom view in Android Studio that would represent the graph (data structure, not bar charts and etc). How can I implement the horizontal scrolling to see all the vertices of the graph in my custom view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your custom view should extend a View with a horizontal scroll (HorizontalScrollView for example)

Answer (score 0):

Use HorizontalScrollView and place your customView inside that.